# Why is this query running slow?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I wonder why doing

```
UserView.where(:user_viewable_type => 'Song').order('created_at desc').limit(5)
```

takes 1213ms to run. Bit slow innit?

In schema.rb `user_viewable_type` is indexed:

```
add_index "user_views", ["user_viewable_type"], :name => "index_views_on_viewable_type"
```

Even in psql:

```
"index_views_on_viewable_type" btree (user_viewable_type)
```

Running with `.explain` returns:

```
UserView.where(:user_viewable_type => 'Song').order('created_at desc').limit(5).explain
  UserView Load (1801.4ms)  SELECT "user_views".* FROM "user_views" WHERE "user_views"."user_viewable_type" = 'Song' ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 5
  EXPLAIN (1.6ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT "user_views".* FROM "user_views" WHERE "user_views"."user_viewable_type" = 'Song' ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 5
=> "EXPLAIN for: SELECT  \"user_views\".* FROM \"user_views\"  WHERE \"user_views\".\"user_viewable_type\" = 'Song' ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 5\n                                  QUERY PLAN\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n Limit  (cost=17113.28..17113.28 rows=5 width=37)\n   ->  Sort  (cost=17113.28..17147.82 rows=69085 width=37)\n         Sort Key: created_at\n         ->  Seq Scan on user_views  (cost=0.00..16883.78 rows=69085 width=37)\n               Filter: ((user_viewable_type)::text = 'Song'::text)\n(5 rows)\n"
```

So I decided to break the query down and remove `order` and I get:

```
UserView.where(:user_viewable_type => 'Song').limit(5).explain
UserView Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "user_views".* FROM "user_views" WHERE "user_views"."user_viewable_type" = 'Song' LIMIT 5
```

It seems that the `order('created_at desc')` was causing the query to be slow. But why? Souldn't order by be fast?

I tried `order` on the the `id` column:

```
UserView.where(:user_viewable_type => 'Song').order('id desc').limit(5).explain
UserView Load (44.8ms)  SELECT "user_views".* FROM "user_views" WHERE "user_views"."user_viewable_type" = 'Song' ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 5
```

So much faster! What could be wrong?

A few things I should mention:

1. If you haven't noticed yet, this is a polymorphic table.
2. In the past, I renamed `:live_viewable_type` to `:user_viewable_type`, via Rails migration via `t.rename :live_viewable_type, :user_viewable_type`. However, I don't think this should be the problem, because the indexes are still on the right column.

Comment: Replace "Explain" in your question with "Explain analyze", and format it as code with line breaks so it's readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue, as far as I can tell, might be that either:

a) You aren't indexed on `created_at`

or:

b) The database is choosing one index or the other (i.e. either using the `created_at` index, making the `user_viewable_type` specification slow, or vice versa).

If you're making these calls frequently it might be worth looking into a combined index on `[created_at, user_viewable_type]` (or the other way: `[user_viewable_type, created_at]`, depending on which will narrow your results more quickly).

Comment: A similar article I've just read, explains your suggestion: http://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-choosing-additional-indexes

Comment: Right, what he wrote is pretty well along the lines I was thinking. If you do an index on `[created_at, user_viewable_type]` are your results better?